# Easiest way to make a button with just a image

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe

I'm using Delphi XE and I would like to make a button which shows just the provided PNG image with transparent background and no additional margins of any kind.

I tried to do this with TButton but I get an ugly gray background with bsPushButton style. If I use bsCommandLink style there is a 10 pixel top margin although all my ImageMargins settings are set to 0.

What would be the easiest way to make this happen?

**EDIT:** It doesn't have to look like a button. I just need it to look exactly like the image it is assigned with. Preferably it should be able to be a tab stop and have various states (enabled, disabled, hover, ...) so I could assign appropriate image to each state.

Comment: what about toolbuttons on a toolbar?

Comment: I don't need a toolbar button but rather one that can be placed freely in UI. Of course I can place toolbars anywhere I like but this feels like an awkward solution to my problem.

Comment: do you want it to look like a button? In fact, could you give us a screenshot of a mockup of how you want it to be?

Comment: Shall it be able to receive focus/be a tab stop?

Comment: It doesn't have to look like a button. I just need it to look exactly like the image it is assigned with. Preferably it should be able to be a tab stop and have various states (enabled, disabled, hover, ...) so I could assign appropriate image to each state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is a transparent control that inherits from [`TWinControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl) since you want it to be able to retrieve focus, this has never been an easy task. However since recent versions Embarcadero has provided a control that provides this. The [`TCustomTransparentControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TCustomTransparentControl) is a `TWinControl` descendent that makes the task a bit easier for you.

So, what I would do is to create a new component, and inherit it from `TCustomTransparentControl`, then what I would do is to overwrite the `Paint` method like this:

```
procedure TMyTransparentButton.Paint;
var
  rc: TRect;
begin
  if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) then
  begin
    // Specify size and location of the image.
    rc := Rect(0, 0, pngImage.Width, pngImage.Height);

    // Draw the image on the canvas.
    pngImage.Draw(Canvas, rc);
  end;
end;
```

By this approach you should be able to get the transparency and translucency you are looking for. However you still need to handle the situation where the button is disabled, pressed, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [TImage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TImage) and assign the [OnClick](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TImage.OnClick) event to mimic a button.  It depends if you need to receive focus or not.

Comment: This feels like a hack. I updated my question to include the missing requirement that I want to change the used image based on the state of the component. For example, I want disabled button to look different than enabled button.

Comment: @Ville Salonen: This is no more a hack than mimicking a button with an image is. *stukelly* doesn't offer intercepting messages on a lower level, but simply using an event that is supported for this component by Delphi, so I would never call that a hack. Anyway, now that you've elaborated more on the requirements, the solution becomes unfitting indeed.

Comment: If you use a standard `TImage`, you can simply display a different image when needed.  To handle hovering, subclass the `TImage.WindowProc` property (or derive a new component and override the `WndProc()` method) so you can intercept `CM_MOUSEENTER` and `CM_MOUSELEAVE` messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could use TPanel and assign the OnClick event to mimic a button. Set the borders of the panel to 'flat' to make it look like there is no panel.

It is similar to the solution proposed by stukelly but it is easier to implement the enabled and hover features. For example, on hover, you can make the panel look 3D.