# Delphi Button with Background Image

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl

I have Delphi 7 and now installed Delphi XE2.
I'm not really experienced with Design, VCL etc. but I would like to have a button (with Caption!) and a simple background image (PNG). I have 3 pictures of custom buttons (1 for click, 1 for mouseoff and 1 for mouseover). I have tried almost everything but I can't seem to find a way to have a simple button with caption in the middle and the images in the background. Please help.

PS.: The button should NOT visually go down on click (this is already in the png image.)

[image: Button ON]
[image: Button OFF]

Comment: TImage + transparent TLabel ? for re-using, fuse them into single component using Custom Containers Pack (i heard it was updated for XE2)

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Apparently a friend of mine has done it in .net (C#) but with a button component.

Comment: C#/.NET button <> Delphi/Win32 common control button.

Comment: I see. Is there maybe a component?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257104/easiest-way-to-make-a-button-with-just-a-image). Search SO for `[delphi] png button`, There are a lot of similar questions with really good answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might adapt this tiny component, no need to install for testing

## Test

```pascal
procedure TForm1.MyOnClick( Sender: TObject );
begin
  ShowMessage( 'Hallo' );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click( Sender: TObject );
begin
  with TImageButton.Create( self ) do
  begin
    Parent := self;
    Images := Imagelist1;
    Index := 0;
    HoverIndex := 1;
    DownIndex := 2;
    Caption := 'test';
    OnClick := MyOnClick;
    Width := Imagelist1.Width;
    Height := Imagelist1.Height;
    Font.Size := 12;
    Font.Style := [fsBold];
  end;
end;
```

[image: Image showing three different images for the same button in default, hover and down state]

## And code

```
unit ImageButton;

// 2013 bummi

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  ExtCtrls, StdCtrls,ImgList;

Type

  TState = (MouseIn, MouseOut, Pressed);

  TImageButton = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FChangeLink:TChangeLink;
    FImages: TCustomImageList;
    FDownIndex: Integer;
    FIndex: Integer;
    FHoverIndex: Integer;
    FState: TState;
    FCaption: String;
    FOwner: TComponent;
    FAutoWidth: Boolean;
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
    procedure CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
    procedure CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_FONTCHANGED;
    procedure WMLBUTTONDOWN(var Message: TMessage); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
    procedure WMLBUTTONUP(var Message: TMessage); message WM_LBUTTONUP;
    procedure SetDownIndex(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetHoverIndex(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetIndex(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetImages(const Value: TCustomImageList);
    procedure SetCaption(const Value: String);
    procedure ImagelistChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetAutoWidth(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure CheckAutoWidth;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; Override;
  published
    property AutoWidth:Boolean read FAutoWidth Write SetAutoWidth;
    property Caption;
    property DownIndex: Integer read FDownIndex Write SetDownIndex;
    property Font;
    property HoverIndex: Integer read FHoverIndex Write SetHoverIndex;
    property Images: TCustomImageList read FImages write SetImages;
    property Index: Integer read FIndex Write SetIndex;
  End;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure TImageButton.ImagelistChange(Sender:TObject);
begin
   invalidate;
   CheckAutoWidth;
end;

Constructor TImageButton.create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FOwner := AOwner;
  FState := MouseOut;
  Width := 200;
  Height := 200;
  FChangeLink:=TChangeLink.Create;
  FChangeLink.OnChange := ImagelistChange;
end;

Destructor TImageButton.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FImages) then FImages.UnRegisterChanges(FChangeLink);
  FChangeLink.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TImageButton.Paint;
var
  ico: TIcon;
  idx: Integer;
  DestRect: TRect;
  L_Caption: String;
begin
  inherited;
  idx := -1;
  if Assigned(FImages) then
  begin
    case FState of
      MouseIn:
        if FImages.Count > HoverIndex then
          idx := HoverIndex;
      MouseOut:
        if FImages.Count > Index then
          idx := Index;
      Pressed:
        if FImages.Count > DownIndex then
          idx := DownIndex;
    end;
    if idx > -1 then
      try
        ico := TIcon.create;
        FImages.GetIcon(idx, ico);
        Canvas.Draw(0, 0, ico);
      finally
        ico.Free;
      end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Canvas.Rectangle(ClientRect);
  end;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  DestRect := ClientRect;
  L_Caption := Caption;
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
  Canvas.TextRect(DestRect, L_Caption, [tfVerticalCenter, tfCenter, tfSingleLine]);
end;


procedure TImageButton.CheckAutoWidth;
begin
  if FAutoWidth and Assigned(FImages) then
    begin
      Width := FImages.Width;
      Height := FImages.Height;
    end;

end;

procedure TImageButton.SetAutoWidth(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FAutoWidth := Value;
  CheckAutoWidth;
end;

procedure TImageButton.SetCaption(const Value: String);
begin
  FCaption := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TImageButton.SetDownIndex(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FDownIndex := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TImageButton.SetHoverIndex(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FHoverIndex := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TImageButton.SetImages(const Value: TCustomImageList);
begin
  if Assigned(FImages) then FImages.UnRegisterChanges(FChangeLink);
  FImages := Value;
  if Assigned(FImages) then
      begin
        FImages.RegisterChanges(FChangeLink);
        FImages.FreeNotification(FOwner);
        CheckAutoWidth;
      end;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TImageButton.SetIndex(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FIndex := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TImageButton.WMLBUTTONDOWN(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  FState := Pressed;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TImageButton.WMLBUTTONUP(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  FState := MouseIn;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TImageButton.CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

Procedure TImageButton.CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage);
Begin
  inherited;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    Exit;
  if FState <> MouseIn then
  begin
    FState := MouseIn;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

Procedure TImageButton.CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage);
Begin
  inherited;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    Exit;
  if FState <> MouseOut then
  begin
    FState := MouseOut;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TImageButton.CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  invalidate;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Own', [TImageButton])
end;

end.
```

Will respect transparencies if use with PNG and Imagelist cd32Bit

Comment: This looks great! Thank you so much! Ausgezeichnet!

Comment: About the auto sizing feature (called `AutoWidth` here). Wouldn't be enough to use built-in `AutoSize` and return the size to the overriden `CanAutoSize` method ?

Comment: @TLama I have not thought of built-in AutoSize, yes there are improvements which could be implemented, could become a never ending story ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can inherit from TBitBtn and override CN_DRAWITEM message handler - this will create a fully normal button with focus,with any pictures you need as a background and with all window messages that buttons need (see BM_XXX messages). You can also implement a virtual method to do other kinds of buttons with just this method overriden.

Something like that:

```
TOwnerDrawBtn = class(TBitBtn)
private
  procedure CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem); message CN_DRAWITEM;
  procedure CMFocusChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_FOCUSCHANGED;
protected
  procedure DrawButton(const DrawItemStruct: TDrawItemStruct); virtual;
end;

procedure TOwnerDrawBtn.CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem);
begin
  DrawButton(Message.DrawItemStruct^);
  Message.Result := Integer(True);
end;

procedure TOwnerDrawBtn.CMFocusChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TOwnerDrawBtn.DrawButton(const DrawItemStruct: TDrawItemStruct);
var 
  Canvas: TCanvas;
begin
  Canvas := TCanvas.Create;
  try
    Canvas.Handle := DrawItemStruct.hDC;

    //do any drawing here
  finally
    Canvas.Handle := 0;
    Canvas.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You Can Simply Use `TJvTransparentButton` from [JEDI-Project JVCL](http://www.delphi-jedi.org) . 
With this component you can use single imagelist for all events and all other buttons , more events with image state , more style, Caption , Glyph, PressOffset and ... .