# Custom Component OnMouseDown not working;

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a button based on TImage with 2 images governed by `OnMouseDown`.
[image]

The component shows the first image when running but I cannot get the `OnMouseDown` event to fire. I have looked through Stack Overflow related questions but cannot find an answer (Maybe I am asking the wrong question).

```
unit ImageBtn;

{$R resources.res resources.rc}

interface

uses WinTypes, WinProcs, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Controls,
Forms, Graphics, Extctrls, AppEvnts, Buttons;

type

  TImageBtn = class(TImage)
    private
      FCenter : Boolean;
      FDoubleBuffered : Boolean;
      procedure AutoInitialize;
      procedure AutoDestroy;
      procedure SetDoubleBuffered(Value : Boolean);
      procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;

    protected
      procedure Click; override;
      procedure Loaded; override;
      procedure Paint; override;
      procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;

    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;

    published
      property OnClick;
      property OnDblClick;
      property OnDragDrop;
      property OnMouseDown;
      property OnMouseMove;
      property OnMouseUp;
      property Center : Boolean read FCenter write FCenter default True;
      property DoubleBuffered : Boolean read FDoubleBuffered write SetDoubleBuffered default True;
      property Height;
      property Proportional default True;
      property Stretch default True;
      property Width;
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('dcs', [TImageBtn]);
end;

procedure TImageBtn.AutoInitialize;
begin
  FCenter := True;
  FDoubleBuffered := True;
  Height := 29;
  Proportional := True;
  Stretch := True;
  Width := 82;
  Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'BITMAP1');
end;

procedure TImageBtn.AutoDestroy;
begin

end;

procedure TImageBtn.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  MouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y);
  Picture.CleanupInstance;
  Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'BITMAP2');
end;

procedure TImageBtn.SetDoubleBuffered(Value : Boolean);
begin
  FDoubleBuffered := Value;
end;

procedure TImageBtn.Click;
begin

inherited Click;
end;

constructor TImageBtn.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  AutoInitialize;
end;

destructor TImageBtn.Destroy;
begin
  AutoDestroy;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TImageBtn.Loaded;
begin
  inherited Loaded;
end;

procedure TImageBtn.Paint;
begin
  inherited Paint;
end;

procedure TImageBtn.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
var
  W, H: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  W := Width;
  H := Height;
  if (W <> Width) or (H <> Height) then
  inherited SetBounds(Left, Top, W, H);
  Message.Result := 0;
end;

end.
```

I have probably made a stupid mistake but I cannot find it. Can anyone help please? Delphi 7 and Windows 11.

**Edit**
Having read Blurry Sterk's comments, maybe I did not make the problem clear. The  `OnMouseDown` event does not seem to fire but I cannot add a breakpoint as there are no blue points.

**Edit2**
Please find screenshot of the only lines that have a blue dot against them.
[image]
This is obviously related to why my code is not working.

**Edit3**
Thank you to everyone who replied. I followed the advice by removing the line `MouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y);` and it worked. BTW I didn't  want to use a TBitBtn because of the frame and alignment. The button needs a shadow. Thank you once again Tom Brunberg and Eirik A.

Comment: I don't have access to development machine at the moment so I can't test your code. But I'm wondering why are you creating a custom component instead of using TBitBtn. TBitBtn is a special button made to show image instead of text. Even more it supports using of different images for different button states which is what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You are calling `inherited Picture.CleanupInstance` in `MouseDown`. Your comment is commenting out the `;` at the end of the first line of `MouseDown` which in affect calls `inherited Picture.CleanupInstance`

Comment: @SilverWarrior 34. Thank you for that i will look into TBitBtn.

Comment: @Blurry Sterk. Thank you for that but it still does not work

Comment: @Learning What does not work; the event not firing or does the second image not show? If you fix the incorrect code as I mentioned then the `OnMouseDown` event (not to be mistaken for the `MouseDown` procedure) should fire. The `inherited` line on its own should have a semi-colon (`;`) for itself

Comment: @Blurry Sterk, I did add the semi-colon and retested it, It seems as the event is not firing. One thing though I cannot add a breakpoint as there are no blue dots

Comment: My experiences are limited when it comes to control development, but I know that calling an event from inside of that same event, is wrong (to say the least). In `TImgBtn.MouseDown()` you call `MouseDown()` resulting in an endless recursive call. I really think you should follow @SilverWarrior 's suggestion.

Comment: You are calling `MouseDown` inside `MouseDown`.
That is what is called `Recursion`. Is that what you want to do? It will loop forever the way you have set it up.

Comment: To continue from my previous comment, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681618/delphi-button-with-background-image). It shows you what messages you should respond to, and provides sample code.

Comment: I tried your code on Delphi7 running on Window 7 and Windows 10 but it didn't produce the problem. Line 119 in your code will always evaluated to FALSE so line 120 will never executed.

Comment: I think you need to call `inherited` after your `picture` methods, in your `MouseDown` event handler.

Comment: I reinstated the recursive call to `MouseDown()`. By removing it, the question becomes meaningless, please don't. Leave question as it was when answered.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg and everyone. Sorry about removing the code. I see now as you say it would be meaningless to any visitor.